# Castelnuovo's rationality criterion following Beauville

Tags: algebraic-geometry, minimal-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

Following Beauville's book "Complex algebraic Surfaces", in order to prove Castelnuovo's rationality criterion i need to prove one lemma and one proposition.

There is one point of proof of lemma V.8 at page 56 that i can't understand.
I'm in the hypothesis that $S$ is a minimal surface with $K^2<0$ (denoting with K the canonical divisor) and i need to find an effective divisor B on $S$ such that
$(K.B)<0$. To do this i look at hyperplane sections.
Let H be an hyperplane section on $S$, if $(H.K)<0$ i win cause B=H is the divisor i'm looking for.

If $(H.K)=0$, Riemann-Roch inequality applied to the divisor $K+nH$ ($n$ positive) gives

$$h^0(K+nH)\geq \chi(\mathcal{O}_S)-\frac{1}{2}((K+nH)^2-((K+nH).K))-h^0(-nH).$$

My assertion is that for sufficiently large $n$, $h^0(K+nH)=dimH^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(K+nH))\geq 0$. But this is true only if for sufficiently large $n$, $h^0(-nH)=dimH^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(-nH))=0$. 
Is the last equality true?

I have the same problem in the proof of Proposition V.6 at page 57.
I'm in the hypotheis that $S$ is a minimal surface with $q(S)=P_2(S)=0$ (then $p_g(S)=0$ and so $\chi(\mathcal{O}_S)=1$). I take a curve $C$ such that $(K.C)<0$, $|K+C|=\emptyset$ and I apply Riemann-Roch inequality at the divisor $K+C$.
I obtain
$$0=h^0(K+C)\geq 1+\frac{1}{2}(C^2+C.K)-h^0(-C).$$
Again I wonder if $h^0(-C)=dimH^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(-C))=0$ and how to prove it.

Comment: The answer to the first question is yes; indeed, for any $n>0$, the line bundle $-nH$ does not have sections. See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519500/negative-multiple-of-ample-line-bundle-has-no-global-section for an explanation. The same logic will apply to any nontrivial effective line bundle, so also applies to $C$ in the second question.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh I have a doubt. So you're telling me that for every non trivial effecive divisor D (even if $D^2<0$), the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_S(-nD)$ does not have sections for any $n>0$. Actually i'm trying to show this with riemann-roch but i can't succeed.

Comment: Yes, I am telling you precisely that. Consider this statement: for a line bundle $L$, if $L$ and its dual $L^*$ both have a nonzero global section, then $L$ is the trivial bundle. Do you believe it?

Comment: If they both had non zero global sections, this would mean that there is an effective divisor linear equivalent to zero, other than zero, that is absurd. So i believe it. Thank you.